# how can I transfer '2021-12-01 08:10:12+00' from string to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.series of strings, each value looks like this '2021-12-01 08:10:12+00' and I want to use pd.to_datetime but i cant find the right thing to put in format field.

tried this pd.to_datetime(clean_data['trading time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S+%f', utc=True) but its not working

Comment: simply use `pd.to_datetime(clean_data['trading time'], dayfirst=False)` or plain `pd.to_datetime(clean_data['trading time'])`

Comment: thanks that was simple then I thought